# Search checklist field data in the Content search API in Sitecore SXA

Tags: sxa, content-search, fieldtype

I would like to search checklist data through the Content search API in the Sitecore SXA. However, it is not searching any data based on checked value in checklist field.

Sharing code :

```
Template:
Name         Type
Topic        CheckList
```

Field in the Content Editor :

[image]

Property :

```
 public string Topic { get; set; }
```

Code I am using for searching:

```
predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Topic.Contains(filters.Topic));
```

We are passing data through filters.
Such as filter value is "Topic 1" here.

Index configuration :

```
<contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <defaultSolrIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" search:require="solr">
          <documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
            <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
               <field fieldName="topic"     type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.ResolvedLinks, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search"  returnType="stringCollection" referenceField="topic"        contentField="title" />
            </fields>
          </documentOptions>
          <fieldMap>
            <fieldNames>
               <field fieldName="topic"      returnType="guid"   storageType="YES" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
            </fieldNames>
          </fieldMap>
        </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
 </indexConfigurations>
</contentSearch>
```

Comment: Have you tried passing ID of the topic 1?

Comment: yes, i have tried this but it was not working.

Comment: @Marek , I am checking Sitecore SXA is not creating any index for this field. Is it the issue ?

Comment: Use solr admin to check if the field is populated and what are the values in it. Then check search.log to see what is the query which is sent to solr.

Comment: Now , it is creating index but still i am not able to fetch result even i tried with both(text , ID)

Comment: Check search.log to see what is the query which is sent to solr

Comment: @Marek , kindly assist me . How to search by passing ID? I am passing this ID value "{KHY786GY-JK68-KG4L-BB63-079208ED42E5} " and query i am using "predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Topic.Equal(new ID(filters.Topic)))" but  it is throwing an error. If i am passing without "new ID()" ever then i am not getting any result.

Comment: I don't know your application. It's not possible to debug it for you. You may want to try assigning the value first and then using it in predicate like `var topicId = new ID(filters.Topic); predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Topic == topicId );` but I don't know if it's gonna work for you. Btw I can see that your field in config is guid and you use `public string Topic { get; set; }`. Maybe try changing it to `guid` or `ID`?

Comment: Okay i will try this and thanks for your assistance

Comment: @Sonu Is this resolved? Can you try List<string> in model instead of string? If ID is not working?

Comment: @Sreekrishnan i am able to get the result for single selected result. if we have result  "{....}|{.....}|{...}" with multiple GUIDs with pipe separated symbol then it is not searching result.

Comment: As far i can see from the config you have provided, at the first line you have given returnType as stringCollection and second time you have given it as guid. Can you just change both of them to either "guidCollection" or "stringCollection". If you use guidCollection try to use IEnumberable<Guid> in model and if string collection try to use IEnumerable<string> in the model. Please let me knw the results.

Comment: Above mentioned functionality is only work if we are passing GUID like this "{me02bfdc3jkb4c438bbdf086ae1e1281}". However if we use string then by default GUID will be like this "{ME02BFDC-BA6E-4D52-BB63-079208ED42E5}. Any suggestion how we can change default guid to {me02bfdc3jkb4c438bbdf086ae1e1281}  pattern without id.